# python-jenkins ImportError

Tags: python, python-3.4, importerror

```
When trying to install python-jenkins module, I get the following error.

 pip3 install jenkins
Collecting jenkins
  Downloading jenkins-1.0.2.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: jenkins
  Running setup.py install for jenkins ... done
Successfully installed jenkins-1.0.2
[root@btpvm0759 ~]# pip3 install python-jenkins
Collecting python-jenkins
  Using cached python-jenkins-0.4.14.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    ERROR:root:Error parsing
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pbr/core.py", line 111, in pbr
        attrs = util.cfg_to_args(path, dist.script_args)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pbr/util.py", line 267, in cfg_to_args
        wrap_commands(kwargs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pbr/util.py", line 569, in wrap_commands
        cmdclass = ep.resolve()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2308, in resolve
        module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
    **ImportError: No module named 'monolithic'
    error in setup command: Error parsing /tmp/pip-build-zuvc150p/python-jenkins/setup.cfg: ImportError: No module named 'monolithic'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-zuvc150p/python-jenkins/**
```

Python version :

*python3
Python 3.4.5 (default, Mar 17 2017, 10:32:53)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.*

Kindly help me with this.

Comment: Seeing this as well, did you ever find a solution?

Comment: bug is there https://bugs.launchpad.net/python-jenkins/+bug/1632345